# Meteor - How to get the ObjectID with findOne() when I search for a field "x"

Tags: events, meteor, objectid

I'm trying to learn Meteor (it's great by the way).

But I don't understand how to get (printed in my console for example) the ID of a document I search with findOne() or anything else.

I didn't find an answer/clue on the internet (wrong keywords?)

A super simple template (an input where we type a "number"):

```
<template name="abc">
<form id="abc">
    <input type="text" name="numberX">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</template>
```

And a super simple "event" (where I try to get the ID of the document with a field = my number):

```
Template.abc.events({
  "submit form": function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
     var input = event.target.numberX.value;
     mycollection.findOne({field:input},{_id: this.id});
     console.log(this);
 }
});
```

Thank you very much for any clue/help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MrE - the point is he doesn't know the `_id`. You need to lookup by field value then get the `_id` of the result:

```
var _id = mycollection.findOne({field:input})._id;
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect! and so simple..Thank you very much.